# how to login and open a new activity in android using json response?

Tags: android, mysql, json

I have a login activity and a signup activity , signup activity creates new user with emailid and password in my mysql database using jsp which is perfectly fine and the details of user is in json format .
My json list looks like this

```
http://192.110.8.4:8082/Server/user_details_json.jsp // url for the below  
     response
{
 Users: [
  {
   user_id: "1",
   password: "123456",
   email_id: "abc.arun@gmail.com"
 },
 {
   user_id: "2",
   password: "456789",
   email_id: "smart_arun@yahoo.com"
 }
 ]
}
```

Now what i would like to do is i want to login in the application using any of the above user details , so i have tried some code , and when i debugged the response is also showing properly , but the application closes abruptly when i click on login button , i want to get the above emailid and password one at a time and check whether it matches the entered text inside edittext.
Can somebody suggest me how to do it ?

```
private static String url =  
   "http://192.110.8.4:8082/Server/user_details_json.jsp";
EditText email_id, password;
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Calling async task to get json
            if (email_id.getText().toString().equals("") && 
                password.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login UnSuccessful", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                new GetUserDetails().execute();
            }

        }
    });

private class GetUserDetails extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String user_emailId;
    String user_password;
    HashMap<String, String> contact;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                users = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_USERS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = users.getJSONObject(i);

                    user_emailId = c.getString("email_id");
                    user_password = c.getString("password");

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_EMAIL_ID, user_emailId);
                    contact.put(TAG_PASSWORD, user_password);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    userList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (email_id.getText().toString().equals(user_emailId) && 
           password.getText().toString().equals(user_password)) {
            Intent in = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Email-id and Password does not 
            match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

My Logcat :

05-08 16:59:12.583: I/global(9037): call createSocket() return a new socket.
05-08 16:59:13.133: D/Response:(9037): > 
05-08 16:59:13.133: D/Response:(9037): 
05-08 16:59:13.133: D/Response:(9037): 
05-08 16:59:13.133: D/Response:(9037): 
05-08 16:59:13.133: D/Response:(9037): 
05-08 16:59:13.133: D/Response:(9037): {"Users":[{"user_id":"1","password":"123456","email_id":"abc.arun@gmail.com"},{"user_id":"2","password":"456789","email_id":"smart_arun@yahoo.com"}]}

05-08 16:59:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(9037): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-08 16:59:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(9037): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-08 16:59:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-08 16:59:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
05-08 16:59:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
05-08 16:59:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
05-08 16:59:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-08 16:59:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-08 16:59:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-08 16:59:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
05-08 16:59:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(9037): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 16:59:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at com.example.shoppingcart.Login$GetUserDetails.doInBackground(Login.java:219)
05-08 16:59:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at com.example.shoppingcart.Login$GetUserDetails.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
05-08 16:59:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-08 16:59:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-08 16:59:13.178: E/AndroidRuntime(9037):     ... 4 more
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037): Activity com.example.shoppingcart.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{412ac5d8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-555,339} that was originally added here
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.shoppingcart.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{412ac5d8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-555,339} that was originally added here
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:458)
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037):  at com.example.shoppingcart.Login$GetUserDetails.onPreExecute(Login.java:185)
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037):  at com.example.shoppingcart.Login$4.onClick(Login.java:123)
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4231)
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17537)
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
05-08 16:59:13.943: E/WindowManager(9037):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Have you add IntentFilter in AndroidManifest.xml for your new Activity. and post your logCat

Comment: @ChiragSavsani yes i have added , check my updated question to see the logcat